# SQL query percentage with 2 tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I’m beginning with SQL and I’m having problems when I would like to run some queries. The database has these two tables:

[image]

I would like to retrieve the name of the teams with “id_equip” 27 and 58 with the percentage of winning matches with between both.

So far I’ve done:

```
SELECT   j.id_eq_local , 
         Avg(res_local) 
FROM     juga AS j 
WHERE    ( 
                  j.id_eq_local = 58 
         OR       j.id_eq_local = 27) 
AND      ( 
                  res_local > res_visitant 
         OR       res_local < res_visitant) 
AND      ( 
                  j.id_eq_visitant = 58 
         OR       j.id_eq_visitant = 27) 
GROUP BY (j.id_eq_local, j.id_eq_visitant);
```

But it doesn’t give the result which is :

Barcelona - 57

Real Madrid - 28

Which means: Barcelona won the 57% of the matches, Real Madrid the 28% and the remainder finished in tie.

Brief explanation of the database:

Table JUGA:

- id_jornada= id of the week
- id_temp= id of the season
- id_lliga= id of the league (in this case must be “ESP”)
- id_eq_local= id of the local team
- id_eq_visitant= id of the guest team
- res_local= local team result
- res_vistitant = guest team result

Table EQUIP:

- id_equip= id of the team
- nom_equip = name of the team

Some samples of the data:
[image]

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, given two teams you want to output each team with the percentage of how much this team has beaten the other team ?

Comment: Only the results between them or against other teams?

Comment: @farghal yes, that is.

Comment: @McNets between them.

Comment: can you show some sample data from the tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use postgre's `filter`-specifier on aggregate functions, which restricts the rows to be considered by the aggregate function to those fulfilling specific conditions. Thereby, we can compare counts over different sets of rows within the same query:

```
select 'Real Madrid' as equip,
  100*(count(*) filter (where (id_eq_local > id_eq_visitant and res_local > res_visitant) OR (id_eq_local < id_eq_visitant and res_local < res_visitant))) / count(*) as percentage
from juga
where id_eq_visitant IN (27,58)
  and id_eq_local IN (27,58)

UNION 

select 'Barcelona' as equip,
  100*(count(*) filter (where (id_eq_local < id_eq_visitant and res_local > res_visitant) OR (id_eq_local > id_eq_visitant and res_local < res_visitant))) / count(*) as percentage
from juga
where id_eq_visitant IN (27,58)
  and id_eq_local IN (27,58)
```

Comment: It doesn't returns anything (Barcelona - 0  Real Madrid 0) :(

Comment: As noted by  @Jeremy Real, I suppose that the results are truncated. See edited answer.

Comment: It works! But I edited what I want to show. It isn't exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Try edited answer. Hope string literals work that way, maybe you have to adapt the '  with something else...

Answer (score 2):

I think this would do it.

```
SELECT (SUM(WIN_58)/SUM(match_count))*100 AS WIN_PCT_58
      ,(SUM(WIN_27)/SUM(match_count))*100 AS WIN_PCT_27
      ,(SUM(TIE)/SUM(match_count))*100 AS TIE_PCT
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as match_count
          ,CASE WHEN res_local > res_visitant THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WIN_58
          ,CASE WHEN res_local = res_visitant THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TIE
          ,CASE WHEN res_local < res_visitant THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WIN_27
    FROM juga AS j
    WHERE j.id_eq_local = 58 AND j.id_eq_visitant = 27
UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as match_count
          ,CASE WHEN res_local < res_visitant THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WIN_58
          ,CASE WHEN res_local = res_visitant THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TIE
          ,CASE WHEN res_local > res_visitant THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WIN_27
    FROM juga AS j
    WHERE j.id_eq_visitant = 58 AND j.id_eq_local = 27
)
```

Comment: ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 2: FROM (
             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.

Comment: Solved. But it returns this percentages: 1.285 and 1.142

Comment: I didn't realize the RES columns were scores. This should work now with edits.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 6: ... ,CASE WHEN res_local > res_visitant THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS WIN_58 :(

Comment: @HessianMad forgot the END on case statements. Fixed.

Comment: It returns nothing (0 - 0 - 0) :(

Comment: @HessianMad It must be truncating the result and not displaying the fraction. Try adding '*100' to each of the output rows. I will edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select (local.local_wins + guest.guest_wins) / (local.cnt + guest.cnt) as Team1,
       (local.guest_wins + guest.local_wins) / (local.cnt + guest.cnt) as Team2
from 
    (select sum(case when res_local > res_visitant then 1 else 0 end) as local_wins, sum(case when res_visitant > res_local then 1 else 0 end) guest_wins, count(*) as cnt
     from JUGA where id_local = 53 and id_guest = 17) local,

    (select sum(case when res_local > res_visitant then 1 else 0 end) as local_wins, sum(case when res_visitant > res_local then 1 else 0 end) as guest_wins, count(*) as cnt 
     from JUGA where id_local = 17 and id_guest = 53) guest
```